# SpringBootApplication is unable to find bean under subpackage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I encountered this error while starting my SpringBootApplication.

```
Description:

Field XXX in com.helloworld.www.batch.SomeServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.helloworld.www.batch.repository.SomeRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.helloworld.www.batch.repository.SomeRepository' in your configuration.
```

This is my project layout where I have my SpringBootApplication and the Repository. I have annotated my SpringBootApplication with "@SpringBootApplication", but it was not able to find "SomeRepository" bean class.

Do I have to annotate it with "EnableJpaRepositories" and indicate the repository packages before it can detect the "SomeRepository" bean class?

```
com.helloworld.www
+SpringBootApplicationName.java
com.helloworld.www.batch.repository
+SomeRepositoryName.java
```

Updates to the post, I have annotated my Repository with @Repository, and it only contains an interface without any implementation classes.

```
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SomeModel, Integer> { }
```

Here's my main application class under package "com.helloworld.www"

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you annotated the repository interface with the @Repository annotation?

Comment: @vincendep That's completely unnecessary.

Comment: So repositories get registered as bean when scanning for components even if they are not annotated?

Comment: I did annotate my class with @Repository.

Comment: Hello, please include the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication in your question

Comment: @EnmanuelRodríguezPaz I have updated my post with the main class

Comment: Thank you, but please include the packages. I'll explain you why I'm asking this: when you use @SpringBootApplication, the application scans for classes/interfaces in every package under this annotated class package. So, if you have you main class "SomeApplication" in the package com.test, the scanning won't include anything under com.helloworld.www, so the SomeRepository bean won't be created

Answer (score 0):

I think its not a "simple" injection problem here.
It looks like you're using spring data.
And the Repository that must be injected is actually an interface rather than concrete bean implementation.

Spring Data engine should be able to "find" your repository and create a real implementation in runtime (backed by Proxy mechanism). Then it puts this generated proxy onto an application context and only after that it can be injected into other beans.

In this case it looks like this "engine" that turns the repository into bean didn't work for some reason, and hence at the moment of instantiation of the service (`SomeServiceImpl`) There is no actual bean that represent (has been generated out of) repository.

Its hard to tell more, because you don't show any spring data related configurations and do not provide the code of that Repository...

Comment: I have annotated my repository interface with @Repository, however, there is no implementation class.